# Cannot resize stack of type template

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

Im trying to resize my stack but my program keeps terminating after the 'cout'. 
On the output terminal it displays 1 and then the program terminates. In this case T is an int and size is set to 10 by default. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


template <typename T>
class stack {

public:

    int topStack;
    T* stack1;
    int size;
    void copy(const stack& other);
    void move(stack&& other);
  // constructor
  stack ();
  // destructor
  ~stack()
  {
        delete[] stack1;
  };
    // copy constructor
    stack (const stack&);
    // copy assignment
    stack& operator= (const stack&);
    // move constructor
    stack (stack&&);
    // move assignment
    stack& operator= (stack&&);

    T& top() const;  // return the top element
    void pop ();  // remove the top element
    void push(const T&); // add element on top of stack
    void push (T&&); // add element on top of stack
    bool empty() const; // is the stack empty?
    void clear(); // remove all elements
    ostream& print(ostream&, stack&);
    void resize();
};

//Default Constructor
template <typename T>
stack<T>::stack()
{
        size=10;
        stack1= new T[size];
        for(int b =0; b < size; b ++)
        {
            stack1[b] = T();
        }
        topStack =-1;

}

//Copy Constructor
template <typename T>
void stack<T>::copy(const stack& other)
{
        topStack = other.topStack;
        stack1= new T[other.size];
        size =other.size;
        for(int i=0; i< other.size ; i++)
        {
            stack1[i]=other.stack1[i];
        }

}

//Copy assignment
template <typename T>
stack<T>& stack<T>::operator =(const stack& other)
{
    if (this == &other) return *this;

    T* store = new T[other.size];
    for(int g =0; g < other.size ; g++)
    {
        store[g]= other.stack1[g];
    }
    delete[] stack1;
    this->stack1 = store;
    this->size = other.size;
    this-> topStack = other.topStack;

    return *this;
}
//Move Constructor
template<typename T>
void stack<T>::move(stack && other)
{
    topStack = other.topStack;
    other.topStack = 0;
    stack1 = other.stack1;
    for(int u =0; u < other.size ; u++)
    {
        other.stack1[u]=0;
    }
    size = other.size;
    other.size=0;
}

//Move assignment
template <typename T>
stack<T>& stack<T>::operator= (stack&& other)
{
    this->size = other.size;
    other.size=0;
    this->topStack = other.topStack;
    other.topStack=0;
    this->stack1 = other.stack1;
    for(int u =0; u < this->size ; u++)
    {
        other.stack1[u]=0;
    }
    return *this;

}
//Checks if stack is empty
template <typename T>
bool stack<T>::empty() const
{
    return topStack == -1;

}

//Resize array
template<typename T>
void stack<T>::resize()
{
    cout << "DAYYYY55UM";
    T* storage = new T[this->size*2];
    cout << "DAYYYYUM";
    for(int r=0; r < this->size ; r++)
    {
            storage[r]= this->stack1[r];
    }
    delete[] this->stack1;
    this->stack1= storage;
    this->size = size*2;

    cout << "DAYYYYUM";

}
//Returns top
template <typename T>
T& stack<T>::top() const
{
    if(empty())
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Stack is empty. "<< endl;
        return;
        //Make a throw catch statement here
    }
    return stack1[topStack];
}
//Pop
template <typename T>
void stack<T>::pop()
{
    if(empty())
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Stack is empty." << endl;
        return;
    }
    stack1[topStack] =0;
    topStack--;

}
//Push
template <typename T>
void stack<T>::push(const T& q)
{
    if(topStack < size)
    {
        topStack++;
        stack1[topStack] = q;
    }else{
    resize();
    }

}
//Push
template <typename T>
void stack<T>::push(T&& q)
{
    if(topStack < size)
    {
         topStack++;
         stack1[topStack] = q;
    }else{
    resize();
    }
}

//Print Function
template <typename T>
ostream& stack<T>::print(ostream& os, stack& other)
{
    os << other.stack1 ;
}

template <typename T>
void stack<T>::clear()
{
    for(int g=0; g < size; g++ )
    {
        stack1[g]=0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    stack<int> world;
    world.push(9);
    world.push(40);
    world.push(40);
     world.push(9);
    world.push(40);
    world.push(40);
     world.push(9);
    world.push(40);
    world.push(40);
     world.push(9);
    world.push(40);
    world.push(40);

    cout << world.stack1[12] << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is T? And size?

Comment: In this case T is an int and size is set to 10 by default

Comment: and for the next magical question: what does the debugger say?

Comment: The debugger doesn't say anything. Hence, the program terminates. "Stacks.exe has stopped working"

Comment: That is weird, are you compiling in debug mode?

Comment: The problem is elsewhere. Not in this code.

Comment: I just posted my whole code. I ran through everything and couldn't find an error

Comment: Is this an STL stack or your very own stack? An STL stack doesn't have a size variable like that. It has a size() function.

Comment: I'm implementing my own stack class

Comment: You're pushing 12 items and then you try to retrieve the 13:th.

Answer (score 0):

That error means that you have an out of bounds array access somewhere that is corrupting malloc's data structures.

The error is in your push function:

```
template <typename T>
void stack<T>::push(T&& q)
{
    if(topStack < size)
    {
         topStack++;
         stack1[topStack] = q;
    }else{
    resize();
    }
}
```

When you write the last item before resize, topStack is one less than size, which is a valid index (the last one, indeed), but then you increment it to size, and write the item in that position, and that's not a valid index.

By the way, you have a lot of errors with the indexes al over your class. My advice woulbe to take into account that c++ arrays start at 0 and end at size-1, and revise your code.

And have you noticed that when you resize the array you don't add the new item?